# Did not receive SMS from Cognito even thought it's a successful request

Tags: amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-identity-js

I'm unable to receive an SMS from using `resendConfirmationCode` method from `amazon-cognito-identity-js`. Even thought the request was sent successfully with a sample response of

```json
{
  AttributeName: "phone_number",
  DeliveryMedium: "SMS",
  Destination: "+*******xxxx"
}
```

I have the following code that will be called once a user submit a form.

```js
function resendConfirmationCode(username) {
  const cognitoUser = new CognitoUser({
    Username: username,
    Pool: userPool,
  });

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    cognitoUser.resendConfirmationCode(function (err, result) {
      if (err) reject(err);
      resolve(result);
    });
  });
}
```

From my perspective, I think my code works well. I have done `signUp`, and the SMS got sent if the user was new. However, when I used the `resendConfirmationCode` I got the above response. I have already verified my phone number in Amazon SNS Sandbox. Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 0):

So I wasn't reading carefully,

Turns out there's a thing called **Account spend limit**, you can check it on Amazon SNS > Text Messaging (SMS) > Text messaging preferences.

I'm glad that Amazon put $1 on default. Apparently I have no idea that we're charged for SMS verification. (A bit naive, but Amazon got most the free stuff so I thought that's somewhat free too).

Thanks AWS! This information is hard to find thought. Hopefully this helps.